# Flyway migrations don't work when the version is 0

Tags: java, spring, flyway

When I have a file with 0 as the version number, Flyway won't pick it up.

Maven dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
    <artifactId>flyway-core</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Spring Configuration:

```
<bean id="flyway" class="org.flywaydb.core.Flyway" init-method="migrate">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="baselineOnMigrate" value="true" />
    <property name="locations" value="classpath:/META-INF/db/" />
    <property name="placeholders">
        <map>
            <entry key="username" value="" />
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Files in classpath:/META-INF/db/

- sql/V0_1__INITIAL_BUILD.sql (creates a table)
- sql/V1_3__from-0.1.sql (adds a column)
- sql/V1_4__from-1.3.sql (adds indexes to the table)

When I start my service, I get this error

```
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
```

This is what gets inserted into the *schema_version* table:

```
COLUMN          |ROW1               |ROW2
version_rank    |1                  |2
installed_rank  |1                  |2
version         |1                  |1.3
description     |Flyway Baseline    |from-0.12
type            |BASELINE           |SQL
script          |Flyway Baseline    |sql/V1_3__from-0.1.sql
checksum        |-993203535         |
installed_by    |DBUSER2            |DBUSER2
installed_on    |25-AUG-15          |25-AUG-15
execution_time  |0                  |120
success         1                   |0
```

It looks like it's ignoring the *sql/V0_1__INITIAL_BUILD.sql* file that actually creates the table and moves immediately to *sql/V1_3__from-0.1.sql* and fails.

The command line tool doesn't seem to have this issue.

Is it just not possible to use 0 as the version number using Spring or am I missing something obvious?

Comment: Did you just pivot your `schema_version` table?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thats correct by default 1 is the **baselineversion** from which it starts executing all scripts in sequence. And in order to override the default version from 1 to 0 pls use following on the flyway config at XML :-

```
<property name="baselineVersion" value="0" />
```

Thanks.